# Opening a specific file with openfiledialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

So I'm trying to make a text file open when I navigate to the file using openfiledialog. Here is my code:

```
        string path;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
               System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            path = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

It will not open, here is the error I get:
 i.imgur.com/0eVWFAJ.png

Comment: Any issues with this?

Comment: yeah, it gives me an error, here it is: http://i.imgur.com/0eVWFAJ.png

Comment: Downvote: No clear question has been asked.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I just realized that. I fixed it

Comment: You still could show more code.  For example, have you new'd openFileDialog?  Did you step through it with your debugger, and if so, which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to open the file on a new window, you should use `Diagnostics.Process`

Like what @Baldric showed, and if you want to save the filename.

```
string path = "";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
}
```

and one more thing I noticed in your code.
you want to return the filename but you use

```
path = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

is the text in the file contain a path of the file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to open the file using the default application. In which case, try this:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

openFileDialog1.FileName contains the string of the full path.

If, instead of opening it, you would rather load the contents of that selected file into another string, try:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    ...
    // your code to work with the string here...
}
```

Comment: "Where should I put it?" you serious? :D

Comment: maybe you do it wrong, but this code is the best way to open a file, But if what you want is to display the text in a textbox, you should use the `IO.StreamReader`.

Comment: No, I want it to open a window where I can navigate to a file. Then I want the program to save the path as a string

Comment: I have a question, is the file a text file?

Comment: Yeah, this is where I want the user to navigate to the file that they want to use. Instead of editing the code manually.